# Parrallel Threads In Code

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I've been learning about threads recently and I am trying to figure out the maximum number of threads that are running in parallel for the following code.

```
void thread_function2(void*) {
    arbitrary_function();
}

void thread_function1(void*) {
    pthread_t thread_info2;
    pthread_create(&thread_info, NULL, thread_function2, NULL);
    thread_function2(NULL);
    pthread_join(thread_info2, NULL);
}

int main(void) {
    pthread_t thread_info;
    pthread_create(&thread_info, NULL, thread_function1, NULL);
    thread_function1(NULL);
    pthread_join (thread_info, NULL);
}
```

What I have figured out so far is that the main thread creates the 1st thread, then the 1st thread creates the 2nd thread. I know that pthread_join blocks the calling thread until the specified thread terminates. In this case would it mean none of the threads are running in parallel? Any ideas for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have more than that. Let's assume, your `arbitrary_function` takes considerable time to execute.

First main() creates a thread and you have 2 of them. Than the second one creates a third one, and waits for it - you have 3 now. Meanwhile, `main()` continues, and runs `thread_function1` directly - which creates another thread. So here you have 4. This is a maximum number, you won't have more than that.